HERE Api Reverse geocode doesn't return a proper city
I use reverse geocoding to get the city based on coordinates. The coordinates are 53.512599, 25.988364 (map link)
Here is what the request looks like, from which I extract items with localityType = city or district:
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=53.512599,25.988364&types=area
In most cases, this works well, but sometimes the request does not return cities.
For the given coordinates, it returns only city "Кореличский район" with city localityType (which actially is not the city but district) but not "Барановичи" I expect:

But if I use discover api to check I see the city exists with city localityType
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Барановичи&types=area

Moreover, the coordinates I'm giving in the first request are much closer to the city Барановичи I expect than to the city Кореличский район that is being returned to me.

What's your programming question? This sounds like an issue with the service, nothing you can do about it.
